# Is there any way to create a new screen without using new Activity class?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing an application . In that I have too many screens for that I am using too many Activity classes . The method which I followed is very poor method.

So I want to know is there any way to create a new screen without using a new Activity class.

And one more thing can I make my Activities like pages which I can slide one from another.

If any one know the answer then please help me.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: cant you just use, when switching to another screen, `setContentView(R.layout.mysecondlayout)`?

Comment: There must be at least 1 activity in your application. And for page like sliding layout try using View Pager - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this in several ways.

Here's a [training class on using Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

and here's a [training class on using horizontal swiping and tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

Answer (score 2):

To change the screen you have to start an activity but to make your app look better you can use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and you can also make your pages slide using the [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).

ViewPager was released as part of the Compatibility Package revision 3 and works with Android 1.6 upwards.

Answer (score 0):

You may use in the following way

```
class Activity{

method1();
method2();
..
void method1(){
setContentView(layout);
}
method2(){
if(case1)
{
setContentView(layout);
}
else if(case2){
setContentView(layout)}
...
}
}
```